# Add lock rotation button to Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: gnome, screen, budgie, display-rotation

I'm having a problem with my HP screen rotation. It works like a smartphone or tablet and it changes the screen display when I move the laptop to the sides.

I know that Gnome has a [Lock Rotation button](https://askubuntu.com/a/876606/681993). And I would like to have the same in Budgie (for what I know, it's based in Gnome, right?). Is there a way to do this?

If not, can I block the screen rotation from the command line?

I'm not looking to unable the accelerometer itself, just to lock the screen rotation when the computer moves.

Thanks a lot!

> descrition: Notebook
>
> product: HP ENVY Notebook (P0D92LA#ABM)
>
> vendor: HP
>
> version: Type1ProductConfigId
>
> serial: CND538C3X9
>
> capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32

Comment: Did you check if there's any way you could lock or disable the screen rotation through BIOS?

Comment: Does this change anything: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false` ?

Comment: Thanks @M.Becerra I wouldn't want to mess with the BIOS for this one. But the gsettings thing was a great lead, I thought it would make it, but it didn't work out for me. It is maybe just for Gnome? My Budgie won't do the trick :(

Comment: Do `sudo apt install dconf-editor` and try to find the setting yourself, as it may be very similar to the one I commented previously, just follow the tree :)

Comment: Even though I follow the path that you mentioned, orientation active set to false does not solve my problem. I don't know what might be going on. Thank you so much anyway @M.Becerra

Comment: Please create an answer and accept it. Don't add "solved" to the question.

Comment: Sure @Rinzwind I didn't know this. I've already answered the question and now I'll edit my original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this thanks to the guys from the IRC #ubuntu-budgie

The right command to solve this for Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 is:

> gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen
>   orientation-lock true

---

The one that M. Becerra mentioned, for what I've read, worked just fine in Ubuntu Budgie 16.04, in case you are using that version the path to type into your console is:

> gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false

Comment: +1 For your effort to self-answer while crediting others. Also, good answer to tell the difference between current and newer releases. Well done.