# Screen rotates 90 degrees after shutting lid

Tags: suspend, laptop, xrandr, 19.10, display-rotation

I've recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my laptop and come across the issue where whenever I close the lid of my laptop to put it to sleep, when I re-open the laptop the screen is rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise. I have tried all three fixes in [this thread] from 18.04 LTS ([Screen Rotates After Closing Laptop Lid HP, Ubuntu 18.04.02](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157163/screen-rotates-after-closing-laptop-lid-hp-ubuntu-18-04-02)) but the only thing that works is the terminal command `xrandr -o normal`.

The fix given in this thread is to create a service which runs the xrandr command every time the system awakes from sleep. This is a bit of pain, so I was wondering if there was any other solution that had arisen between 18.04 and 19.10.

The laptop I am using is a Acer Spin SP513-51-311K.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 screen orientation spontaneously changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874487/ubuntu-gnome-16-10-screen-orientation-spontaneously-changes)

Comment: What happens when you hold down Ctrl and Alt keys while pressing each arrow key? another option would be to add `xrandr -o normal` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file. Then, all you have to do is open your terminal emulator, and that command runs automatically—Ctrl+Alt+T. I have `xrandr` commands added to my `.bashrc` file for a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've reinstalled the iio-sensor-proxy package from apt and restarted my laptop. This seems to have fixed the issue.

Uninstall:
`sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy`

Reinstall:
`sudo apt-get install iio-sensor-proxy`