# Laptop wakes up from suspend due to rotation

Tags: suspend, power-management, lenovo, wakeup

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga 3rd Gen. My laptop often wakes up from suspend just because I rotated it, e.g. when I put it into a rucksack. Is it possible that the rotation sensor for the screen is waking up the laptop? (In the BIOS settings, I've already set the Sleep State to Linux instead of Windows 10, and I've disabled rotating displays in the XFCE desktop environment which I'm using.)

Comment: Please start with OS & release details; it tells us what software stack you're asking about.

Comment: Depending on the OS, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1191269/1222991) may prove useful 

Comment: Thanks for comments! I added the OS version Ubuntu 20.04. Will try the solution in the lined answer.